# Know if an element has been saved or updated Nhibernate

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, nhibernate

I'm trying to figure this out, but so far I haven't found any appropiate answer.
I'm coding a SQLite DB app in C# and at certain point I use `session.SaveOrUpdate(object)` in order to save the element to the DB or update it

But depending on which operation has been done (save or update) I need to do different things, so my question is, is there a way to know using SaveOrUpdate method if the object has been saved for the first time or if it's been updated?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `SaveOrUpdate` method is void, therefore, we have to do the check in our code. see:

[9.4.2. Updating detached objects](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-updating-detached)

We should provide setting `unsaved-value` in the mapping:

> NHibernate distinguishes "new" (unsaved) instances from "existing"
>   (saved or loaded in a previous session) instances by the value of
>   their identifier (or version, or timestamp) property. The
>   unsaved-value attribute of the  (or `<version>`, or `<timestamp>`)
>   mapping specifies which values should be interpreted as representing a
>   "new" instance.
>
> ```
> <id name="Id" type="Int64" column="uid" unsaved-value="0">
>     <generator class="hilo"/>
> </id>
> ```

Because otherwise:

> If unsaved-value is not specified for a class, NHibernate will attempt
>   to guess it by creating an instance of the class using the no-argument
>   constructor and reading the property value from the instance.

Next step is just to check that setting against the isntance to be passed into `SaveOrUpdate`

And if we did set the `unsaved-value="0"`, we can check what would happen even before `SaveOrUpdate()` is called:

```
entity.ID == default(int);
```

Comment: Thanks Radim, i've thought that even SaveOrUpdate is a void method, it could be some property in the session variable that could say if the last operation has been a save or an update... but as you said I have to check "manually" what has been